# how to dynamically change font colour based on text value in td element

Tags: html, css, node.js, typescript, asp.net-web-api

[image]

Basically, under the columns Palindrome,Authorised, and Enabled, I need to change their colors according to their text value. I.e. if it says yes in those columns, the text should be green and red if it says no. A ternary operator is used to determine a value. I have been given a coding assessment for interview selection and I'm not too familiar with typescript and node.js

**people-list.html**

```
<template>
  
  <h2 class="title">${heading}</h2>
  <table class="table is-striped is-fullwidth">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Palindrome</th>
        <th>Authorised</th>
        <th>Enabled</th>
        <th>Colours</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <!--
        TODO: Step 6
        Add styles to Palindrome, Authorised and Enabled values.
        When the value is Yes the text colour should be Green.
        When the value is No the text colour should be Red.
      -->

      <tr repeat.for="person of people" person.bind="person">
        <td><a class="is-link" href="/people/${person.id}">${person.fullName}</a></td>
        <td id="palindrome">${person.palindrome ? 'Yes' : 'No' }</td>
        <td>${person.authorised ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</td>
        <td>${person.enabled ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</td>
        <td>${person.colours | colourNames }</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var palinResult = document.getElementById("palindrome").nodeValue

        console.log(palinResult);

        if (palinResult === "Yes") {

            palinResult.fontcolor("green");

        } else if (palinResult === "No") {

            palinResult.fontcolor("red");

        }

    </script>

</template>
```

**people-list.ts**

```
import { autoinject, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { Person } from '../models/person';
import { IPerson } from '../interfaces/iperson';



@autoinject
export class PeopleList {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  heading = 'People';

  @bindable people: Person[] = [];

  async activate() {
    const response = await this.http.fetch('/people');
    const people = await response.json();

    this.people = people.map((person: IPerson) => new Person(person));
  }
}
```

**people.ts - Model**

```
import { computedFrom } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { IPerson } from '../interfaces/iperson';
import { IColour } from '../interfaces/icolour';

export class Person implements IPerson {

  constructor(person: IPerson) {
    this.id = person.id;
    this.firstName = person.firstName;
    this.lastName = person.lastName;
    this.authorised = person.authorised;
    this.enabled = person.enabled;
    this.colours = person.colours;
  }

  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  authorised: boolean;
  enabled: boolean;
  colours: IColour[];

  @computedFrom('firstName', 'lastName')
  get fullName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  @computedFrom('fullName')
  get palindrome(): boolean {

      var s = this.fullName;
      var lowerS = s.toLowerCase()
      var newS = lowerS.replace(/ /g, "");

      //console.log(newS.split('').reverse().join('') === newS);

      return newS.split('').reverse().join('') === newS; //returns boolean to use be used in ternary operator in people-list.html file


  }
}
```

Comment: Does this have to be solved in typescript or node.js? If not, I can give you an answer using a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript if labels were used.  Alternatively, I can give you an answer using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with aurelia framework so maybe wrong syntax, but you can use inline styles to achieve something like that.

```
<td style='color:${person.authorised ? "green": "red}'></td>
```

Comment: much appreciated sir